# Каждую секунду GET запрос с сайта

Tags: http, get

Здравствуйте! Я новичок, постигаю азы так сказать. Есть у меня сайт. Он пустой ещё. По логу вижу идёт каждую секунду GET запрос с одного и того же сайта я уже посмотрел откуда. Поскольку сайт пустой, все GET запросы возвращают 404. Вопроса у меня два.

1. для чего это делается?
2. как в таких случаях правильно поступать?

Ну и немножко лога:

```
::ffff:111.222.333.444 - - [12/May/2017:12:07:50 +0000] "GET /upload/iblock/bf2/bf2c466d663c5d2ac2387ef97b7702da.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3224 "http://altera-auto.ru/Renault/logan/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=yandex&utm_campaign=24125894&utm_content=none.0&yclid=2548162217642037392" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 YaBrowser/17.3.1.840 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
::ffff:111.222.333.444 - - [12/May/2017:12:07:51 +0000] "GET /upload/iblock/8f1/8f14a8171709add974b5fdbe306f54cc.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3224 "http://altera-auto.ru/Renault/logan/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=yandex&utm_campaign=24125894&utm_content=none.0&yclid=2548162217642037392" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 YaBrowser/17.3.1.840 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
::ffff:111.222.333.444 - - [12/May/2017:12:07:54 +0000] "GET /upload/iblock/21d/21dfcf40784f89a08b5021b2db4b3f49.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3224 "http://altera-auto.ru/Hyundai/Solaris_Sedan_New/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=yandex&utm_campaign=24125894&utm_content=none.0&yclid=2548163180989256302" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-J510FN Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 YaBrowser/17.3.1.369.00 Mobile Safari/537.36"
::ffff:111.222.333.444 - - [12/May/2017:12:07:54 +0000] "GET /upload/iblock/82d/82d6fdd69866c49d55293ca17c2f426a.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3224 "http://altera-auto.ru/Hyundai/Solaris_Sedan_New/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=yandex&utm_campaign=24125894&utm_content=none.0&yclid=2548163180989256302" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-J510FN Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 YaBrowser/17.3.1.369.00 Mobile Safari/537.36"
::ffff:111.222.333.444 - - [12/May/2017:12:07:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1967 "-" "BitrixCloud Monitoring/1.0"
::ffff:111.222.333.444 - - [12/May/2017:12:08:00 +0000] "GET /upload/iblock/c0d/c0d53131b91acca7fd8da68b97bd7d2d.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3224 "http://altera-auto.ru/Volkswagen/Polo_Sedan/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=avito.ru&utm_campaign=14446842&utm_term=volkswagen%20polo%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&yclid=2548165279573874510" "Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; Windows Phone 8.1; Android 4.0; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; NOKIA; Lumia 720) like iPhone OS 7_0_3 Mac OS X AppleWebKit/537 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537"
::ffff:111.222.333.444 - - [12/May/2017:12:08:00 +0000] "GET /upload/iblock/1f7/1f7fc5d905ef47115618ceb188f8052f.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3224 "http://altera-auto.ru/Volkswagen/Polo_Sedan/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=avito.ru&utm_campaign=14446842&utm_term=volkswagen%20polo%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&yclid=2548165279573874510" "Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; Windows Phone 8.1; Android 4.0; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; NOKIA; Lumia 720) like iPhone OS 7_0_3 Mac OS X AppleWebKit/537 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537"
```

Comment: радуйтесь - сайта еще нет, а кто-то нетерпеливо его ждет :)

Comment: Думаю пока просто сидеть наблюдать)

Comment: С какого ip опрашивают ваш сайт?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, цель тут не важна. Скорее всего, человек просто хотел посмотреть, что у меня получится с сайтом, и получится ли, поэтому повесил такую вот штучку-дёргалку. Она обычно используется, чтобы воровать уникальные выражения на сайтах. Грамотным решением в такой ситуации считается сделать редирект по реферу. Для этого в nginx есть специальная директива [ngx_http_referer_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html). Она позволяет защититься от бессмысленных запросов через браузер, которые обычно используются для парсинга и тп.